# Module 'firebase' does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

When trying to run my react-native project I get the following error. 
I think the error might be in the podfile but I cant seem to locate it.

[image]

Below I have added the files which I think are important and could be effecting the error

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ExerFit_mobileapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.7",
    "firebase": "^5.5.9",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-precise-range-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "qs": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-custom-tabs": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "rn-apple-healthkit": "^0.6.5",
    "switch-button-react-native": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "detox": "^15.1.4",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|static-container|expo|@expo|react-navigation|rn-apple-healthkit|switch-button-react-native|native-base))"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/e2e"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    }

  },
  "detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "specs": "e2e",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExerFit_mobileapp.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/ExerFit_mobileapp.xcworkspace -scheme ExerFit_mobileapp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "type": "iPhone 8"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ExerFit_mobileapp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  # add pods for any other desired Firebase products
  # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

  # Pods for ExerFit_mobileapp

  target 'ExerFit_mobileapp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

  end

  target 'ExerFit_mobileappTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'ExerFit_mobileapp-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ExerFit_mobileapp-tvOS


end
```

This project had been working before today and when I began working on it I was getting this error. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.